# After create Winform application with devexpress, what i need to install on the machine that run this application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I create `Winforms` application with `devexpress` and after take this application into another machine without `devexpress` the application cannot start, i need to install something else on th running machine ?

Comment: it'll need whatever .NET version you used

Comment: So its not working this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no need to redistribute our XML files. They are only used at design time.
2. You should redistribute those DLLs which are referenced by your application. By default, all our DLLs are located in the "\DevExpress XXXX.X\Components\Bin" folder ("\DevExpress XXXX.X\Components\Sources\DevExpress.DLL\" for versions prior 11.2).
3. When installing your application, you can place our DLLs in the same folder where your distributed EXE is located.
4. Another approach is to register them in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) using the Gacutil tool.

Note: Distribution of our design DLLs which end with "Design.dll" is prohibited.

reference: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A4

Comment: Just take the DLLs from devexpress folder ?

Comment: Yes you can use the DLL's from the DevExpress folder. You should set the `Copy Local` property of the DevExpress DLL's (in the Visual Studio References) to `true`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: The ones that are in your `References` section in the `Solution Explorer` in Visual Studio. Please don't forget to mark my reply as answered if this answered your question.

Comment: 1. Select the DLL (in references) and go to the properties window in Visual Studio. 
or
2. Select the DLL (in references) and press F4.